# iohook remembers old keypress events

Tags: javascript

I am using `iohook` to capture keypresses(shift + space) during an activity.

For the first time iohook behaves as it should.

`{shiftKey: false, altKey: true, ctrlKey: false, metaKey: false, keychar: 113, …}`

I stop iohook when the activity completes.

But when I restart the activity and start iohook it gives me previous keypress event.

For example, If I press space, then the event I get is like this

`{shiftKey: false, altKey: true, ctrlKey: false, metaKey: false, keychar: 32, …}`

Notice I hadn't press altkey again but it is coming  true.